# How to get more than 40 windows in GNU screen under Debian

Tags: terminal, debian, gnu-screen

I am using the terminal program called screen, which can create several "virtual terminals" in a single "real" terminal (the words "virtual" and "real" here are quite relative, the "real" terminal can be a konsole tab as well, not necessarily tty1-tty6). The problem is that I cannot create more than 40 windows inside a single screen. When I try to create more, screen says "No more windows." After some googling I found that that this is controlled by something called MAXWIN, but I didn't find any information how to modify this MAXWIN. How can I increase the maximal number of windows inside a single screen?

I use Debian 6 "squeeze".

PS I understand that I can run several screen's in several "real" (in the above sense) terminals, but this makes it harder to use multiple display mode (screen -x).

Comment: I think this is a very valid question. Programmers need lots of screens, programmers working on OpenStack development with DevStack need even more. Screen is "the way" developers run DevStack for dev and testing. I just hit this same problem and this question (and answer!) saved me hours.

Comment: This is a valid question, related to programming in bash.

Answer (score 6):

That's a compile time option.  Using strictly packages from upstream, it can't be done.  If you wanted to compile screen yourself, you could accomplish this.  Look in the `config.h.in` file.  Near the top will be `# define MAXWIN 40`. Change that to your new limit.

([more info](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/01/msg01003.html))